# Rails has_many nested attributes in a separate form/view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

I found plenty of example on how to construct a multi-model form and multi-model display. But what if I want to have separate forms and displays?

post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Bas
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessible :comments_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

posts_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.comments.build
  ...
end
```

routes.db:

```
resources posts do
  resources comments
end
```

I have a link to post comments index in my post index:

views/posts/index.html.erb:

```
...
<%= link_to 'Comments', post_comments_path(post) %>
...
```

Post and Comment each have their own scaffold generated form (not nested).

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
...

<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
...
```

In the comments index I loop over post comments:

views/comments/index.html.erb:

```
<% @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) %>  //works fine  
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Yet after adding a new comment (under a specific post id) *the table in the post comments index is **empty!***

Please help.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

In the comments forms it should be:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>
...
```

Paths should be used like:

```
post_comments_path(@post)
edit_post_comment_path(@post,@comment)
```

etc.

In the Comments controller:

```
def index
    @post= Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comments= @post.comments.all
...

def show
    @post= Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment= @post.comments.find(params[:id])
...
```

etc.

Hope others will find this useful!

Comment: I get this error at index view...
Couldn't find <model> without an ID